# How are Chaotic systems different from Ill-posed systems?

Tags: soft-question, chaos-theory

I got puzzled when I thought of two concepts that is 1) Chaotic Systems 2)Well posed and ill-posed systems.

Chaotic systems are those dynamical systems which have the sensitive dependence to the initial conditions if the initial conditions change slightly then the dynamics of the systems change drastically.

Well posed systems have unique solutions and every system possesses the solution and the solution behavior changes continuously with the initial conditions.
and if the system is not well-posed then we say that the system is ill-posed.

How are the two systems different?

Comment: I assume you are talking of differentiable dynamical systems (differentiable semigroup of diffeomorphisms of manifold), the flow of a system of ODE for instance, and if the defining function is $C^2$ it is well-posed -on some time interval, and common systems have solutions for all time. Now there is no standard definition of "chaotic". One is to have positive Lyapunov exponents in some parts and in some directions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent . In a compact manifold this will usually be accompanied by negative Lyapunov exponents, yielding existence of hyperbolic subsets.

Comment: [2/3] So basically well-posedness is a given for common finite-dimensional dynamical systems, and chaos is also pretty common and it is a property that is not really related to well-posedness, at least in differentiable dynamics. But the study of dynamical system has reached some depth and one may find subtleties. There is also the question of genericity of different types of hyperbolicity or distributions of Lyapunov exponents -Lyapunov spectra. You would have to read standard textbooks on dynamical systems, refine your questions, see what interests you.

Comment: [3/3] I should add that there is a global theory of chaos, "ergodic theory": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory. One considers the transformation of the whole phase space and studies whether it is ergodic with respect to some measures, that is roughly whether time and space averages coincide, whether it is mixing, a stronger property, etc. We don't care so much about the local structure of the dynamics as above -eg well posedness is not really a question. But there is an interplay. The ideas of dynamics, eg ergodicity, also have applications to number theory. It is all pretty vast.

Comment: [Bonus] Actually i should also mention that 2 notions close to that of positive Lyapunov exponent are that of (large) condition number, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number, and that of instability (which is basically a fixed point having positive lyapunov exponents in some or all directions). There is another somewhat related notion: that of stiff differential equation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation, where some numerical approximations may be very bad, because the solutions are somehow "kinked" and the numerical method is ill suited to treat such features.

Answer (score 2):

> if the initial conditions change slightly then the dynamics of the systems change drastically.

You probably are thinking of this, but the dynamics do **not** change; rather the ending state at some time in the future does. The behavior of the system looks different, but the dynamics are the same. Also, the solutions of chaotic systems can change continuously with initial conditions. Which by your definition, is not the case for ill-posed problems, hence you can have well-posed chaotic systems.

Comment: Nice! but can you add some mathematical examples of well posed and ill posed chaotic systems?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry. Maybe @Wrzlprmft can?

Comment: Added an example of a well-posed chaotic system

Comment: The given example is *not* chaotic by any reasonable definition.